# Ordering a query by the string length of one of the fields

Tags: lucene, ravendb, lucene.net

In RavenDB (build 2330) I'm trying to order my results by the string length of one of the indexed terms.

```
var result = session.Query<Entity, IndexDefinition>()
                    .Where(condition)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Token.Length);
```

However the results look to be un-sorted. Is this possible in RavenDB (or via a Lucene query) and if so what is the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a field to IndexDefinition to order by, and [define the SortOption](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/querying/static-indexes/customizing-results-order) to Int or something more appropriate (however you don't want to use String which is default).

If you want to use the Linq API like in your example you need to add a field named Token_Length to the index' Map function (see Matt's comment):

```
from doc in docs
     select new
     {
         ...
         Token_Length = doc.TokenLength
     }
```

And then you can query using the Linq API:

```
var result = session.Query<Entity, IndexDefinition>()
                    .Where(condition)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Token.Length);
```

Or if you really want the field to be called TokenLength (or something other than Token_Length) you can use a LuceneQuery:

```
from doc in docs
     select new 
     {
         ...
         TokenLength = doc.Token.Length
     }
```

And you'd query like this:

```
var result = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Entity, IndexDefinition>()
                    .Where(condition)
                    .OrderBy("TokenLength");
```

Comment: Yes.  But also, if the field is indexed using the name `Token_Length`, then he can just use the linq query shown in the original question.  (The default translating convention for this is to map periods to underscores.)  The important part, as you mentioned, is to define the sort order as int.